# Update both state and props in react-redux form on same Submit button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

I am very new to react so it could get lousy.

I started with wizard form from https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/examples/wizard/ and to trying to submit form and change page on same submit click.

I mean, submit form on WizardFormSecondPage and change page to WizardFormThirdPage to show values. Up to now I managed to submit form and change page but separately and struggling to connect both events on same button click.

Maybe it is possible to validate props with statement in  
and trigger .state?
(Of course syntactically it is wrong but just trying to show idea)

```
class WizardForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this)
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      page: 1
    }
  }
  nextPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page + 1 })
  }
  previousPage() {
    this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 })
  }

  render() {
    const { onSubmit } = this.props
    const { page } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        {page === 1 && <WizardFormFirstPage onSubmit={this.nextPage} />}
        {page === 2 && (
          <WizardFormSecondPage
            previousPage={this.previousPage}
            if(onSubmit={onSubmit}) {
             this.nextPage
             }
          />
        )}
        {page === 3 && (
          <WizardFormThirdPage

          />
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

WizardForm.propTypes = {
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default WizardForm
```

**UPDATE:**
So another idea would be render third page from `showResults.js` that is called from `index.js` on `<WizardForm onSubmit={showResults} />`

```
import React from "react";

const testField = () => (
  <div>
   <h1>TEST</h1>
  </div>
);

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

export default (async function showResults(values) {
  await sleep(500); // simulate server latency
  console.log(`You submitted:\n\n${JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}`);
  testField;
});
```

By default, `showResults` return `console.log` with submitted fields info, now i am trying just to render plain div but without any decent results. May someone tell where the point is missed and what could be best practices to create `showResults` component?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want values from page two to display on page three? If they're all being added to your state you should be able to access them on subsequent pages the same way you'd normally access them.

Comment: @MattD Actually, I want to see submitted values on page three. Biggest struggle is to submit form on second page and jump to third page with same Submit click.

Comment: You could add some sort of delay in going to page three, or a loading graphic to be displayed on page three until the data is there. If you're managing state properly it shouldn't take that long for the information you want to display to be available, though. Notice how the data you enter in  the example in the documentation is displayed via an alert window almost instantly. Unless something fails in submitting your form items back to, I'm assuming, the server, all of that information is *already available to you.*

Comment: @MattD take a look at updated question. Would it be possible to render third page with results from `showResults.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form has solved my problem, it is much more functional and easier to use.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. Link only answers are frowned upon, and in this case it's to a GitHub repo that could wind up drastically changed and/or deleted and thus the answer ends up being useless.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a:

```
class WizardFormSecondPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.myHandleSubmit = this.myHandleSubmit.bind(this)
 }
  myHandleSubmit(){
    this.props.handleSubmit()
    this.props.nextPage()
 }
....
....
<Form onSubmit={this.myHandleSubmit}> 
}
```

So Basically pass that custom Handler to your form or button!